# Unusual SQL Server query with "select top 1 @arastr = k"

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
select  top 1 @arastr = k
from    #m
where   datalength(k) = (select max(datalength(k)) from #m)
```

What does this query do, and what is the point of `select top 1 @arastr = k`? This query is taken from a stored procedure which has been working for 7-8 years, so there is nothing wrong with the query, but I could not understand what it does.

(`#m` is a temp table which is created in the early part of the query.)

Comment: you are not funny Nathan. You changed the question, now people do not get the point of the question. People leaving asking questions to this site because of people like you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite common (but a little old fashioned) way to get the value of k into the (previously declared!) variable  @arastr for later usage.

The function DATALENGTH will measure the length of e.g. a VARCHAR.

With TOP 1 you geht in any case only one result row, the one with the "longest" k, it's value is in @arastr afterwards...

EDIT: As pointed out by @jpw this will be random, if there is more than one k with the same (longest) length.

Without knowing, what #m looks like and what kind of data is in 'k' I cannot tell you any more.

Comment: Thanks Shnugo. That is right. After i run the code in another db instance with same table, gave exactly expected results as your tips.

Answer (score 3):

The query select one random value (since `top` is used without an `order by` clause) from the column `k` in the temporary table `#m` and assigns it to a variable `@arastr` (which has been previously declared supposedly). The string selected will be any matching the longest (measured in bytes (by the datalength function)) string in the table.

Comment: No, the value will not be random as the WHERE will pick the "longest" k

Comment: @Shnugo And what if there is more than one value having the property of being longest... Just because you can down vote doesn't mean you should... The query is non-deterministic.

Comment: yes, You're rigth... If there are several entries with the same length being the longest, it will be random. Please edit your answer, so I can upvote it again!

Answer (score -1):

probably makes more sense if it looks like this

```
SET @arastr = (SELECT TOP 1 k
                FROM    #m
                WHERE   DATALENGTH(k) = (SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(k)) FROM #m))
```